# Ruby: handling hashes in the parameters of a method

Tags: ruby, hash, each, key-value, parameters

I have to write a  `tag` method in Ruby:

```
tag(:div, id: 'notification_panel', class: 'alert alert-danger')
```

which should return the follow string (an HTML tag with its attributes and values):

```
=> <div id="notification_panel" class="alert alert-danger">
```

This is my **tag** method:

```
def tag(name, *params)
    result = "<#{name} "
    params.each { |key, value| result << "#{key}=#\"#{value}\"  "  }
    result << " >"
end
```

But the shell returns me the follow string:

```
=> "<div {:id=>\"notification_panel\", :class=>\"alert alert-danger\"}=#\"\"   >"
```

I don't know why it returns me the symbol and not the value of the symbol (e.g. `id` instead of `:id`) and it puts me `\`,  `=>`, `{`, `}` in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*params` will give you an `Array` of the remaining parameters, which will consist of a single `Hash`. `each` will thus fire only once, with `key` being the `Hash`, and `value` being `nil` (because `Array#each` only passes one parameter to its `yield`). `#{key}` will then call `to_s` on the `Hash`, giving you `{:id=>"notification_panel", :class=>"alert alert-danger"}`.

`**params` will give you a `Hash` of the remaining keyword parameters, which is what you wanted (in newer Ruby).

Alternatively, in all Rubies, you can do this:

```
def tag(name, params)
```

which should do the same thing in this case, pretty much.

Comment: Thank you! i understand that! So, i tried to change `*params`  to `**params` but the irb throw me an exception `SyntaxError: (irb):11: syntax error, unexpected tPOW, expecting ')'`

Comment: Then you have an older Ruby, that does not yet support keyword arguments. Use the other method (with just `params`).

Comment: Thak you! i 've tried `def tag(name, params)` and it works great !! Excellent!!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing `tag()` like this:

```
def tag(name, params)
  "<#{name} #{params.map { |k,v| "#{k}=\"#{v}\"" }.join(' ')}>"
end

puts tag(:div, id: 'notification_panel', class: 'alert alert-danger')
  #=> <div id="notification_panel" class="alert alert-danger">
```